# Serial port can't send out data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm doing a project on serial port.. but after i changed my serial comm port into combo box selection, i cant seems to transmit anything data out. here's my codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace XSP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string RxString;
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("RxString");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Load += Form1_Load;

            serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var serialPort1 = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            cbCommPorts.DataSource = serialPort1;
        }

        public static byte[] ConvertToBinary(string str)
        {
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            return encoding.GetBytes(str);
        }

        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (cbCommPorts.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You selected port '{0}'", cbCommPorts.SelectedItem));
                Connect(cbCommPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a port first");
            }

        }

        private void Connect(string portName)
        {
            var serialPort1 = new SerialPort(portName);
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
                serialPort1.Open();

                btnTransmit.Enabled = true;
                btn2.Enabled = true;
                btn3.Enabled = true;
                btnOpen.Enabled = false;
                btnClose.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        private void btnTransmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                string value = "12345";
                serialPort1.Write(value);
            }
            else serialPort1.Close();
        }

        private void txtReceive_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen) return;
            char[] buff = new char[1];
            buff[0] = e.KeyChar;
            serialPort1.Write(buff, 0, 1);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtReceive.AppendText(RxString);
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived
            (object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
        }

        private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
             System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
                sr.Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            btnOpen.Enabled = true;
            btnClose.Enabled = false;
            btnTransmit.Enabled = false;
            btn2.Enabled = false;
            btn3.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to point out where my error lies in? Thanks

Comment: Did you debug your code? What is an error message? Be more spesific.

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on the if statement above where you send the data? I guess this one is false which prevents sending data...

Comment: I can run the whole program. but when i press btnTransmit, there is no data being sent out..

Comment: How about writing a simple test application where you just open the port, try to send data, close the port? The problem with your code is that it is very complex to see when the port is opened, when it is closed, etc. For example: Why is the port closed when it is already in closed state in `btnTransmit`?

Comment: I'm using an if-else method.. if the serialPort1 is closed/not opened, it will automatically close the serial port. Before adding the combo box, i can send out the codes smoothly.. Only after when i change into combo box for selection of serial comm then, the transmitting part stop functioning.

Comment: Iam little confused. Do you mean that you are able to get it to work by giving the comm port name hardcoded and cannot get it to work when you select the port name from combo box?

Comment: yes.. Previously, i set the comm port name manually. (eg: COM1), and by using the same method, i can transmit out the data. But after i change to combo box selection, it can't send out any data despite using back the same transmitting codes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options possible here, but we need more information to tackle this problem. To start off, make sure you are actually sending data. to do this try a breakpoint on the if statement above where you send the data. And step into the code using `F10` and see whether you are actually sending any data.

If you are sending data, your code runs fine and  check the receiver application. check baudrates etc...